# Getting ? when alerting the ajax response or posting it to a text field

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have created an ajax call in jquery to my server, the trouble I'm facing now is that my response is printing ? even though the correct integer value is written into the output stream. Ajax function is given below.

```
$dntb.on('click', 'button', function(event) {
                var i = $(this).closest('tr').index(); //have to get the row where the button is clicked 
                var sditmId = $("#sditm").val();
                var sdhedId = $("#sdhed").val();
                $.get('getstock', {
                    sditmId: sditmId,
                    sdhedId: sdhedId
                }, function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    var stk = ""+response;
                    $("#stk").val(stk);
                });
            });
```

This function is called on click of an issue button in my table shown below

[image: Issue button in display notes page]

The server code is given below

```
int stk = null;
switch (userPath) {
        case "/getstock":
            stk = opo.getStockData(request.getParameter("sditmId") request.getParameter("sdhedId")); //value to write into the output stream.
            break;
        case "/temp":
            //er = opo.checkCatUniqueForEdit(request.getParameter("catName"), request.getParameter("catId"));
            break;
    }
System.out.println(stk); //Printing correctly
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.getWriter().write(stk);
```

Code to get the value

```
public int getStockData(String sditm, String sdhed) {
    int stk = 0;
    try {
        String query = "Select stk.Stk_instk from tbstk stk inner join tbsditm itm on itm.Sditm_prdid=stk.Stk_prdid where itm.Sditm_sdhed=" + sdhed + " and itm.Sditm_id=" + sditm;
        Statement stmt = dcon.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            stk = rs.getInt("Stk_instk");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Op_OrdConf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return stk;
}
```

The ajax call happens successfully but when I alert the response I'm getting and I'm getting the value correctly in the server but in the client side it is ?. Please help me solve this

Comment: you are returning response in content type html, mention explicit data type in $.get(). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but seems that you are missing a comma here:

```
stk = opo.getStockData(request.getParameter("sditmId"), request.getParameter("sdhedId"));
//----------------------------------------------------^-----i think this is missing.
```

As per your comment i would suggest you to explicitly set the `dataType` to `html`:

```
$.get('getstock', {
  sditmId: sditmId,
  sdhedId: sdhedId
}, function(response) {
  alert(response);
  var stk = "" + response;
  $("#stk").val(stk);
},"html"); //<----------add the dataType here.
```

Comment: I accidentally deleted the comma while adding the post. The function calls are happening properly, so that's not it, it is only in the client side I'm getting the response as ?, so is the problem related to writing in the outputstream

Comment: @Manesh oh!! then i guess you should explicitly give the `dataType` to your `$.get()` request.

Comment: I found what the problem is what the function returns is  an integer value so I'm getting a ? in the ajax side

Answer (score 0):

I converted the int value returning from the function as given below to String, it seems to be some conflict between the content type and the value written into the output stream

```
stk = opo.getStockData(request.getParameter("sditmId") request.getParameter("sdhedId"));
```